# Use the cpu 100%

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I need a function that will use my cpu 100% . I have a single core cpu any ideas ?

Does the thread need to be set in high priority ?

Comment: downvote and closing reason please ...

Comment: It wasnt me, but I was tempted to do the same.... Only after reading the first answer I got the point of the question. It sounded like you wanted to outsmart the os to steal cpu cycles from others.....

Comment: Be aware whht what you are suggesting may slow down those threads of the same priority, will not affect those of higher priority and cripple those of lower priority - they will only be able to get CPU via. the OS anti-starvation algorithm which only gives a temporary priority boost every 30 seconds.  Raising one CPU-loop thread to very high priority on a single-CPU box is likely to generate the need for a 'power switch' reset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example, by the next thread:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Classes;

type
  TLoadThread = class(TThread)
  public
    class var Stop: Boolean;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

implementation

constructor TLoadThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FreeOnTerminate:= True;
end;

procedure TLoadThread.Execute;
begin
  repeat until Stop;
end;

end.
```

A usage example:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses Unit2;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure LoadCPU;
begin
  TLoadThread.Stop:= False;
  TLoadThread.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LoadCPU;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TLoadThread.Stop:= True;
end;
```

if your CPU has N cores, click `Button1` N times to reach 100% CPU load; no need to increase thread priority.

Comment: Easier to do while not Terminated

Comment: to call terminate you need to keep object reference which is inconvenient here.

Comment: Hadn't spotted the FreeOnTerminate. I never use that myself. Don't like to give up control.

Answer (score 7):

A loop (infinite) usually does the job fine:

```
while true do begin

end;
```

Obviously forcing the CPU go to 100% without doing anything useful should be done only for academic purposes and on your own hardware and never in any real application that you intend to ship.

Comment: Also, if you wish to have an active GUI while this is in progress, you'll need to spawn this in a seperate (non-GUI aka background-worker) thread. Also, if you have multiple CPU's/cores or hyperthreading, you'll need as many threads as there are virtual CPU's.

Comment: Happy Christmas Darin. Time for a day off surely! :-)

Comment: I do this while loop all the time ... inadvertently.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - why are you still here then?  Are all the bars shut in Cumbria or are you barred/hungover after last night... :)